# How to enable postgresql Automatic backup on windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, backup

I'm trying to backup postgresql on Windows, but I do not know the correct setting for `pgAdmin.so`. How do I enable postgresql Automatic backup on windows?

Comment: *i add pgAgent but i do know setting...*

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link and adapt it to your convenience. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows